# GCC won't compile to an executable file

Tags: command-line, compiling, gcc

I was able to reproduce this issue with a simple case (shown below). The problem in particular is that the output of compiling my main C file is a file with format `data` (returned by running `file` on the file). When the file is run, the command line gives the error `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`.

The file, main.c contains the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    return 0;
}
```

I am using this command to compile the code: `gcc main.c -o main`.

Output of `gcc --version`:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Any thoughts, comments, or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I still don't know why this was happening, but I was able to compile properly from a different computer with the same (or similar) specs.

Comment: How are you running the compiled program? I'd suggest always using ./main just so that you don't pick up main from anywhere else from $PATH

Comment: Yes, that is how I run my executables on linux. The issue is that using `file` on an executable should give you a whole bunch of information about the bitness and the file format, but running `file` on main gives the output `data` (i.e. not an executable file). I think @gslin's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your gcc might be corrupted, try to re-install gcc-4.8:

```
apt-get install --reinstall gcc-4.8
```

Comment: I agree this is likely the issue. I don't have permission, but I'll let an admin know. Thanks.